# New dynamic volume (loop) missed after restart centos

Tags: centos7, lvm, disk-volume

I have Centos on my physical drive. new volume created like commands below:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=cinder-volumes bs=1 count=0 seek=50G
losetup /dev/loop3 cinder-volumes
fdisk /dev/loop3
n
p
1
ENTER
ENTER
t
8e
w
pvcreate /dev/loop3
```

All things goes right and I was happy. but after reboot, this volume missed. whats is the problem? thanks
[image: Befor Reboot]
[image: After Reboot]

Comment: can anyone help me?!

Comment: loop devices are not recreated after reboot. This looks like OpenStack, so perhaps openstack could do so? Or you have to do it yourself.